# Is the STL map container optimized (balanced tree) while constructed?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

If I insert an **ordered** (increasing) sequence of elements into a map, will the final binary tree be somehow optimized? Or will every element have a child "to it's right"? That would make such a tree very inefficient, since **then** the lookup would be linear.

I couldn't find any detailed information about the insertion process into STL map.

Comment: This is strictly implementation dependent and you should not really rely on implementation specific behaviors unless you don't worry about portability.You should only rely on the *behavior* that an `std::map` is supposed to exhibit.

Comment: @Als There's a difference between "relying on implmenentation specific behaviors" and knowing how behaviors are implemented from the point of view of understanding.

Comment: @Benj: And that is the reason I posted it as an comment, Are you objecting to that?

Comment: You both are very right. Often people tend to _rely_ on these informations - although I just wanted to know. :-)

Comment: @HWende: If you want to know, read the code of the STL, you can download it for free. If otoh you are talking about the c++ standard library, and not about the stl, then you should read the particular implementation that you are using. It can be implemented in different ways, and although rb trees are most common, you will surely find different implementations e.g. skiplists, avl trees, b trees...

Comment: "balanced" tree requires that it not degenerate into an expensive linked-list, as your question contemplates.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The C++11 standard (23.1) mandates logarithmic complexity for both `insert` and `find` for associative containers. Constructing them from two iterators `i` and `j` such that `[i, j)` denotes a suitably sorted range of values is even required to have linear time complexity. Whether that means that "the final binary tree is optimized", or whether maps are binary trees at all, is left unspecified.

In practice, though, `std::set`, `std::map` and their multi-friends are virtually always red-black trees, since that's what the original HP/SGI reference implementation of the STL had, and all modern C++ libraries that I know derive from that implementation.

Comment: +1 Because it answers the question within the boundaries of the specifications of standardese.

Comment: @larsmans: In practice `std::map` are implemented as binary trees (red-black or avl) because of several constraints: 1. Forbidden to mute when accessed by `const` methods, 2. Elements must be stable in memory. I recently asked about using skip-lists, but apparently they performed worse. Splay Trees violates `1`, B Trees (and variants) violates `2`. With hindsight, I think that `2` should have been challenged, as B Trees provide better performance (more memory friendly thus more cache friendly).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I'd come to the same conclusion wrt. splay trees and skipt lists, but hadn't thought of B-trees yet. I suspect a B-tree or 2-3 tree *can* be used at the expense of an extra level of indirection, though.

Comment: @larsmans: but the advantage of using them is for better memory locality, which you lose if you add another level of indirection. This is why I believe that stability should not be part of the basics requirements (it has nothing to do with the complexity) and it should be up to the user to decide whether or not they need that extra indirection.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: true. However, I do understand the stability requirement because the library allows arbitrarily large structures to be stored in `std::map`; in a specialized container like a pointer map, this requirement can be lifted.

Comment: @larsmans: yes, this is a potential issue in C++03 (though I do not know how likely it is) but it could have been worked around in the same way that stability was. In C++11 however it no longer makes sense because of move semantics and `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

In general, a `std::map` is implemented using a red-black tree, which is self-balancing. So yes, it's optimized.

If you insert ordered data, the self-balancing will probably take less, since swaps between nodes will not be that frequent.

Comment: Well, thanks! Do you have any reference for this information? (no offense!)

Comment: @HWende none taken. I don't have a reference because it's implementation defined. That's why I said "in general". The standard does guarantee some time limits, so you'll definitely not get O(n) for insert or delete, but O(log(n)).

Comment: Feeding sorted data into a self-balancing tree ALWAYS requires that it waste a lot of time re-balancing as it creates the tree, so the 2nd statement is incorrect. For large data sets, it's better to read them in randomly if possible.

Answer (score 1):

C++ standart requires logarithmic access time for any element in std::map (23.4.4.3 of ISO/IEC 14882) so std::map has to be implemented as self-balancing tree.

Answer (score 0):

The `set` and `map` usually does tree balancing so find is O(log n). Many of the operations' complexity are shown here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Answer (score 0):

It is optimized!

Take a look at [SGI's Standard Template Library Programmer's Guide](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/). You will find the following complexity specifications for inserting and finding elements:

> - Average complexity for insert range is at most O(N * log(size() + N)),
> - where N is j - i. Average complexity for find is at most logarithmic.

Comment: On that particular STL library implementation, which isn't the standard library.

Comment: @juanchopanza: But it is /the/ STL. Last time I checked the standard didn't define anything called STL.

Comment: @PlasmaHH but the SGI docs refer to the SGI STL, which doesn't completely map to the C++ standard library. I am assuming OP meant the standard library, not the STL...

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well, I am (and some others probably too) assume that the OP means the STL. Maybe because the OP mentioned STL ... Quite often people mean X when they say X. Unless they are girls. But this is getting offtopic now.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I think STL is still an exception. Quite often people say "STL" and they mean "the C++ standard library bit with the containers, the algorithms and that templatey stuff"

Comment: @juanchopanza: That still doesn't make the standard define the term STL. And with C++11, does STL now mean the C++03 part of what they called STL? everything that was added in C++11 that has templates? or only containers? or only containers and algorithms?